# VBA issue - cannot get range correct

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a file I extract from an online database that gets pulled down with the columns offset by 1 or two cells for each row. I take this file and paste it in to my working file which has a number of VBA modules running. However the code I have in place for module 1 to format and correct the raw data isn't 100% doing what I want.

I want the code to copy, format and replace only in the range from A5:R, and for all remaining cells to be unaffected as there is a second module that updates existing formulas in all columns past R. The below is the code I have right now:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Generate_Summary_Output_Sheet()
    'Generates a new sheet containing a compact set of summary rows.
    'If the expected headers are not detected in A1:B1 the macro will quit execution.
    'The rows are looped through first time to align the cell in column B with the summary row.
    'In the second loop after a new sheet is added, only summary rows are copied through to the output sheet.
    'The new output replaces the original raw data.
    
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim ReadRow As Integer
    Dim WriteRow As Integer
    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Dim strSheetName As String
    
    If Range("A4").Value <> "Project Code" Or Range("B4").Value <> "Project Name" Then
        MsgBox "The sheet you are trying to activate the macro on is invalid.", vbExclamation, "Incorrect Sheet Detected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For ReadRow = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    'Loop through all rows
        With Range("B" & ReadRow)
            If .Value Like "* Summary" Then
            'Reached a summary label row
                .Offset(1).Value = .Value
                .ClearContents
            End If
        End With
    Next ReadRow
    
    Set shtSource = ActiveSheet
    strSheetName = shtSource.Name
    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    'Adding a new output sheet
    
    WriteRow = 2
    Range("A4:R4").Value = shtSource.Range("A4:R4").Value
    'Copy headers row to the output sheet
    For ReadRow = 2 To LastRow
    'Loop through all rows
        If shtSource.Range("A" & ReadRow).Value Like "*:* Summary" Then
        'Reached a summary row
            Range("A" & WriteRow & ":R" & WriteRow).Value = shtSource.Range("A" & ReadRow & ":R" & ReadRow).Value
            'Transfer summary row to the output sheet
            WriteRow = WriteRow + 1
        End If
    Next ReadRow
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    shtSource.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Name = strSheetName
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Set shtSource = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In terms of function the code does what I want. But I've structured it in such a way that it replaces the whole worksheet and not just a range and fixed set of columns. Does anyone know how I could rewrite to do the action within the one sheet and not affect any columns other than A:R and from row 5 down?

Any advice folks?

Comment: My advice: Use the debugger and check at which place the code is doing something different then what you expect. You should disable the line `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` while debugging so that you can have a look to your data while debugging. And you should qualify all ranges so that your code doesn't rely on `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Try to use Range with reference to a sheet, so not just Range. See mistake [#5](https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/7-common-vba-mistakes-to-avoid/).